# Overlay border-top on vertical navigation

Tags: html, css

I have this vertical navigation ([Here is the jFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kr7e5p6a/))

```
<style>
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

li{
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10;
  border-top: 1px dashed #08C;
}

li:hover{
  background-color: #08C;
}
</style>

<ul>
<li>Abc</li>
<li>Test 2</li>
<li>Test 3</li>
<li>Test 4</li>
</ul>
```

A hovered li should be pure blue without any dashed lines on it. Thus, I want that on a hovered li the surrounding dashed border to be solid. It is no problem to change **border-top** of the hovered li to solid, but I don't know how to change the **border-top** of the next li element.

I am looking for a simple solution without javaScript.

In short, I would like to get on a hover this:
[image]

instead of (what I am currently getting) this:

[image]

One solution that came to my mind was to set **border-top** and **border-bot** of each li as dashed and on hover to solid. But then, the blue hovered li would be surrounded by 2 dashed lines, so this idea does not work.

Are there any good solutions for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try modifying the next sibling, like this

```
li:hover + li {
  border: solid 1px #08C;
}
```

See **[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kr7e5p6a/3/)**

Updated based on comments

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10;
  border-top: 1px dashed #08C;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: #08C;
}
li:hover + li {
  border-top: solid 1px #08C;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Abc</li>
  <li>Test 2</li>
  <li>Test 3</li>
  <li>Test 4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: For this approach, I would suggest changing the `border-style` to solid on hover rather than removing it completely, otherwise the list will jump around slightly as you're hovering.

Answer (score 4):

You could give each `li` a negative margin-top so that the hover background will cover the border:

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

li{
  display: block;
  margin:-1px 0 0 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px dashed #08C;
}

li:hover{
  background-color: #08C;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Abc</li>
<li>Test 2</li>
<li>Test 3</li>
<li>Test 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I vote for ochi's answer, but I would like to point out another solution based on `outline`:

```css
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

li{
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10;
  border-top: 1px dashed #08C;
}

li:hover{
  background-color: #08C;
  outline:1px solid #08C;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Abc</li>
<li>Test 2</li>
<li>Test 3</li>
<li>Test 4</li>
</ul>
```

Outline just overpaints the border.

Similarly `box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px #08C;` does not overpaint but shine through between the dots of the dotted border.

Answer (score -1):

Wow! I am new here but i will like to contribute my twopence to your question:

This are my solution which i think may be of help:

Do you know anything about the CSS "nth-child" selector which can help you in customizing your block elements in way which suites you? for instance you can try this:

```css
  p:nth-child(odd) {
    color: green;
  }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <p>use the nth child</p>
  <!...odd 1...>
  <p>use the nth child</p>
  <!...even 2...>
  <p>use the nth child</p>
  <!...odd 3...>
  <p>use the nth child</p>
  <!...even 4...>
  <p>use the nth child</p>
  <!...odd 5...>
  <p>use the nth child</p>
  <!...even 6...>
</body>
<html>
```

This will change those odd block elements to green.

I guess with you knowledge in html you can use this example for your list items background and hover background.

Other values can be the consecutive numbers you want the style to apply to.

Thanks!